# I dont understand how to use it or what it does, _loadResourcesAsync from react native expo default project with screens

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, expo

in the App.js from the default projects that react-native generates when you use Expo, (The one with diferent screens).

Well, in the App.js.

```
  render() {
if (!this.state.isLoadingComplete && !this.props.skipLoadingScreen) {
  return (
    <AppLoading
      startAsync={this._loadResourcesAsync}
      onError={this._handleLoadingError}
      onFinish={this._handleFinishLoading}
    />
  );
} else {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
    {/* <Text>{User.nom}</Text> */}
    <AppNavigator  style={styles.container} />
    </View>
  );
}
}
     _loadResourcesAsync = async () => {
        return Promise.all([
          Asset.loadAsync([
            require('./assets/images/icon_llaurar.jpg'),
            require('./assets/images/icon_podar.jpg'),
            require('./assets/images/icon_ensofatar.jpg'),
          ]),
          Font.loadAsync({
            // This is the font that we are using for our tab bar
            ...Icon.Ionicons.font,
            // We include SpaceMono because we use it in HomeScreen.js. Feel free
            // to remove this if you are not using it in your app
            'space-mono': require('./assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf'),
          }),
        ]);
      };
```

I really don't understand what it does, or how to use the assets that are loaded. I still have to import every asset on all the screens to use it, so I dont get what to do with it or what it does.

Also, can someone explain what does the line ...Icon.Ionicons.font does? The three dots in front what they are?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st things 1st : From the documentation [AppLoading](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-loading) "(...)React component that tells Expo to keep the app loading screen open if it is the first and only component rendered in your app." .

Regarding assets caching you could also read the expo doc for [Preloading & Caching Assets](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/preloading-and-caching-assets.html) .
Asset.loadAsync will download each asset data to a local file in the device's cache directory.

About the ... that you mention, this is the JavaScript expression for [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) , which makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables. In other words it's understood that Icon.Ionicons.font is an array or object, for which in this case all its items will be spread as direct properties of the object passed as argument to Font.loadAsync().